# Object disappears in game engine

Tags: game-engine

I am working in the game engine. I have tracked camera to follow the ball. When I play the animation, ball appears for half the time and then it disappears. Also the colors in the background do not appear. Only black color appears.

Also when I start it in game logic and start the standalone player, nothing is displayed. Please help me.

How can I share my .blend file here?

Its kind of urgent... please

[image]

I've removed the animation. Can someone tell me why do the colors disappear?

Comment: You can upload your file to [Blend- Exchange](http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/) and edit the resulting link into your question.

Comment: The file is quite large... 111MB...

Comment: A ball with a ground should be less then 1MB. Better prepare a simple demo file. We really do not want the other things. [edit] there are 13Mb of data. How to use this file?